# [django]Automatize changing value reach at my value

Tags: django

### Question

If `istek.yorumlar_set.all` reach at Istek.hedef I want change Istek.publish value to false
But,  How do this is :D
If yours want to other models,  i do upload

Model file  :

```
class Istek(models.Model):
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    baslik = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zaman = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    kime = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sebep = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    aciklama = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    hangidua = models.ForeignKey(Dualar)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,editable=False)
    hedef = models.IntegerField(help_text="Toplam da kaç dua istiyorsunuz : ")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.baslik
    def save(self,*args , **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.baslik)
        super(Istek,self).save()
class Yorumlar(models.Model):
    isim = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    websitesi = models.URLField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    yorum = models.TextField()
    dua = models.ForeignKey(Istek)
    zaman = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.yorum
    def __str__(self):
        return self.isim+" : " +self.websitesi
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['zaman']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Is this what you want to achieve?

```
class Istek(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self,*args , **kwargs):
        if self.yorumlar_set.count() > self.hedef:
            self.publish = False
        ...
```

Comment: Yes,like mean to archive , but save method run after the reach hedef (mean target ) 
Sorry bad english

Comment: So... Is my answer what you're looking for or not?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I try your solution,its work thx.I'm research your solution.I can use your solution or Django Signals.So so so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this problem.Used django.signals.

Here code:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Yorumlar)
def change_true_or_false(instance,created,**kwargs):
    instance.dua.toplamdua += 1
    if instance.dua.toplamdua > instance.dua.hedef:
        instance.dua.publish = False
        instance.dua.save()
    else:
        instance.dua.save()
```